# trouble with calculating using javascript

Tags: javascript

I can't get this calculator to work, any ideas:

```
 //start of the calculator
 var price;
 var aclevel = PHD;
 var paperugency = 10 - 23hrs;
 var pages = 10;
 var papertype = writing;
 if (papertype === ppt) {
     if (paperugency == "10-23hrs") {
         price = parseInt("28");
     }
     if (paperugency == "24hrs") {
         price = parseInt("21");
     }
     if (paperugency == "2-3days") {
         price = parseInt("14");
     }
     if (paperugency == "3-4days") {
         price = parseInt("13");
     }
     if (paperugency == "4-5days") {
         price = parseInt("12");
     }
     if (paperugency == "5-6days") {
         price = parseInt("11");
     }
     if (paperugency == "7-9days") {
         price = parseInt("10");
     }
     if (paperugency == "10-13days") {
         price = parseInt("9");
     }
     if (paperugency == "14-20days") {
         price = parseInt("8");
     }
     if (paperugency == "21-29days") {
         price = parseInt("7");
     }
     if (paperugency == "30days+") {
         price = parseInt("5");
     }

 }
 //editing service
 if (papertype === "editing" && aclevel === "HS") {
     if (paperugency == "10-23hrs") {
         price = parseFloat("21.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "24hrs") {
         price = parseFloat("19.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "2-3days") {
         price = parseFloat("17.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "3-4days") {
         price = parseFloat("15.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "4-5days") {
         price = parseFloat("14.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "5-6days") {
         price = parseFloat("13.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "7-9days") {
         price = parseFloat("12.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "10-13days") {
         price = parseFloat("11.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "14-20days") {
         price = parseFloat("10.95");
     }
     if (paperugency == "21-29days") {
         price = parseFloat("9.95");
     }
     if (paperugency == "30days+") {
         price = parseFloat("8.95");
     }
 }
 if (papertype === "editing" && aclevel === "CLLG") {
     if (paperugency == "10-23hrs") {
         price = parseFloat("24.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "24hrs") {
         price = parseFloat("22.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "2-3days") {
         price = parseFloat("20.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "3-4days") {
         price = parseFloat("18.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "4-5days") {
         price = parseFloat("17.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "5-6days") {
         price = parseFloat("16.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "7-9days") {
         price = parseFloat("15.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "10-13days") {
         price = parseFloat("14.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "14-20days") {
         price = parseFloat("13.95");
     }
     if (paperugency == "21-29days") {
         price = parseFloat("12.95");
     }
     if (paperugency == "30days+") {
         price = parseFloat("11.95");
     }
 }
 if (papertype === "editing" && aclevel === "UGT") {
     if (paperugency == "10-23hrs") {
         price = parseFloat("25.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "24hrs") {
         price = parseFloat("23.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "2-3days") {
         price = parseFloat("21.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "3-4days") {
         price = parseFloat("19.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "4-5days") {
         price = parseFloat("18.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "5-6days") {
         price = parseFloat("17.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "7-9days") {
         price = parseFloat("16.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "10-13days") {
         price = parseFloat("15.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "14-20days") {
         price = parseFloat("14.95");
     }
     if (paperugency == "21-29days") {
         price = parseFloat("13.95");
     }
     if (paperugency == "30days+") {
         price = parseFloat("12.95");
     }
 }
 if (papertype === "editing" && aclevel === "PHD") {
     if (paperugency == "10-23hrs") {
         price = parseFloat("30.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "24hrs") {
         price = parseFloat("28.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "2-3days") {
         price = parseFloat("26.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "3-4days") {
         price = parseFloat("24.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "4-5days") {
         price = parseFloat("23.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "5-6days") {
         price = parseFloat("22.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "7-9days") {
         price = parseFloat("21.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "10-13days") {
         price = parseFloat("20.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "14-20days") {
         price = parseFloat("19.95");
     }
     if (paperugency == "21-29days") {
         price = parseFloat("18.95");
     }
     if (paperugency == "30days+") {
         price = parseFloat("17.95");
     }
 }
 if (papertype === "editing" && aclevel === "MST") {
     if (paperugency == "10-23hrs") {
         price = parseFloat("28.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "24hrs") {
         price = parseFloat("26.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "2-3days") {
         price = parseFloat("24.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "3-4days") {
         price = parseFloat("22.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "4-5days") {
         price = parseFloat("21.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "5-6days") {
         price = parseFloat("20.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "7-9days") {
         price = parseFloat("19.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "10-13days") {
         price = parseFloat("18.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "14-20days") {
         price = parseFloat("17.95");
     }
     if (paperugency == "21-29days") {
         price = parseFloat("16.95");
     }
     if (paperugency == "30days+") {
         price = parseFloat("15.95");
     }
 }

 //writing service
 if (papertype === "writing" && aclevel === "HS") {
     if (paperugency == "10-23hrs") {
         price = parseFloat("33.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "24hrs") {
         price = parseFloat("30.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "2-3days") {
         price = parseFloat("20.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "3-4days") {
         price = parseFloat("18.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "4-5days") {
         price = parseFloat("17.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "5-6days") {
         price = parseFloat("16.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "7-9days") {
         price = parseFloat("15.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "10-13days") {
         price = parseFloat("14.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "14-20days") {
         price = parseFloat("12.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "21-29days") {
         price = parseFloat("11.95");
     }
     if (paperugency == "30days+") {
         price = parseFloat("10.95");
     }
 }
 if (papertype === "writing" && aclevel === "CLLG") {
     if (paperugency == "10-23hrs") {
         price = parseFloat("35.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "24hrs") {
         price = parseFloat("33.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "2-3days") {
         price = parseFloat("22.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "3-4days") {
         price = parseFloat("21.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "4-5days") {
         price = parseFloat("20.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "5-6days") {
         price = parseFloat("19.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "7-9days") {
         price = parseFloat("18.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "10-13days") {
         price = parseFloat("17.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "14-20days") {
         price = parseFloat("16.95");
     }
     if (paperugency == "21-29days") {
         price = parseFloat("15.95");
     }
     if (paperugency == "30days+") {
         price = parseFloat("14.95");
     }
 }
 if (papertype === "writing" && aclevel === "UGT") {
     if (paperugency == "10-23hrs") {
         price = parseFloat("40");
     }
     if (paperugency == "24hrs") {
         price = parseFloat("35.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "2-3days") {
         price = parseFloat("25.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "3-4days") {
         price = parseFloat("24.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "4-5days") {
         price = parseFloat("23.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "5-6days") {
         price = parseFloat("22.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "7-9days") {
         price = parseFloat("21.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "10-13days") {
         price = parseFloat("20.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "14-20days") {
         price = parseFloat("18.95");
     }
     if (paperugency == "21-29days") {
         price = parseFloat("17.95");
     }
     if (paperugency == "30days+") {
         price = parseFloat("16.95");
     }
 }
 if (papertype === "writing" && aclevel === "PHD") {
     if (paperugency == "10-23hrs") {
         price = parseFloat("45");
     }
     if (paperugency == "24hrs") {
         price = parseFloat("37.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "2-3days") {
         price = parseFloat("31.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "3-4days") {
         price = parseFloat("30.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "4-5days") {
         price = parseFloat("28.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "5-6days") {
         price = parseFloat("27.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "7-9days") {
         price = parseFloat("26.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "10-13days") {
         price = parseFloat("25.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "14-20days") {
         price = parseFloat("23.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "21-29days") {
         price = parseFloat("22.95");
     }
     if (paperugency == "30days+") {
         price = parseFloat("21.95");
     }
 }
 if (papertype === "writing" && aclevel === "MST") {
     if (paperugency == "10-23hrs") {
         price = parseFloat("42");
     }
     if (paperugency == "24hrs") {
         price = parseFloat("35.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "2-3days") {
         price = parseFloat("30.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "3-4days") {
         price = parseFloat("26.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "4-5days") {
         price = parseFloat("25.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "5-6days") {
         price = parseFloat("24.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "7-9days") {
         price = parseFloat("23.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "10-13days") {
         price = parseFloat("22.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "14-20days") {
         price = parseFloat("20.50");
     }
     if (paperugency == "21-29days") {
         price = parseFloat("19.95");
     }
     if (paperugency == "30days+") {
         price = parseFloat("18.95");
     }
 }

 var total = "$" + (price * pages).toFixed(2);;
 alert(total);
```

Comment: Post minimum relevant code, format it properly, post what error did you encounter with the code

Comment: Why do you `parseInt` and `parseFloat` string literals? Wouldn't it be simpler to just say `price = 28;` and so on?

Answer (score 0):

There was some error in the code, you have define a string but have not added any quote.

```
var aclevel="PHD"; 
var paperugency="10-23hrs"; 
var pages=10; 
var papertype="writing"; 
if(papertype==="ppt"){
```

Comment: how cani then output the toatl in a form text field

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this by a form then you can do the following, but in that case you have to check if all the inputs exists or it's valid or not using if block at the start of the function.

```
 <body>
<script>
    function test(){
        var price;
        var aclevel=document.getElementById('acclevel').value;;
        var paperugency=document.getElementById('paperurgency').value;
        var pages=document.getElementById('pages').value;
        var papertype=document.getElementById('papertype').value;;
        if(papertype==="ppt"){
            if(paperugency=="10-23hrs"){
                price=parseInt("28");}
            if(paperugency=="24hrs"){
                price=parseInt("21");}
            if(paperugency=="2-3days"){
                price=parseInt("14");}
            if(paperugency=="3-4days"){
                price=parseInt("13");}
            if(paperugency=="4-5days"){
                price=parseInt("12");}
            if(paperugency=="5-6days"){
                price=parseInt("11");}
            if(paperugency=="7-9days"){
                price=parseInt("10");}
            if(paperugency=="10-13days"){
                price=parseInt("9");}
            if(paperugency=="14-20days"){
                price=parseInt("8");}
            if(paperugency=="21-29days"){
                price=parseInt("7");}
            if(paperugency=="30days+"){
                price=parseInt("5");}

        }
        //editing service
        if(papertype==="editing" && aclevel==="HS"){
            if(paperugency=="10-23hrs"){
                price=parseFloat("21.50");}
            if(paperugency=="24hrs"){
                price=parseFloat("19.50");}
            if(paperugency=="2-3days"){
                price=parseFloat("17.50");}
            if(paperugency=="3-4days"){
                price=parseFloat("15.50");}
            if(paperugency=="4-5days"){
                price=parseFloat("14.50");}
            if(paperugency=="5-6days"){
                price=parseFloat("13.50");}
            if(paperugency=="7-9days"){
                price=parseFloat("12.50");}
            if(paperugency=="10-13days"){
                price=parseFloat("11.50");}
            if(paperugency=="14-20days"){
                price=parseFloat("10.95");}
            if(paperugency=="21-29days"){
                price=parseFloat("9.95");}
            if(paperugency=="30days+"){
                price=parseFloat("8.95");}
        }
        if(papertype==="editing" && aclevel==="CLLG"){
            if(paperugency=="10-23hrs"){
                price=parseFloat("24.50");}
            if(paperugency=="24hrs"){
                price=parseFloat("22.50");}
            if(paperugency=="2-3days"){
                price=parseFloat("20.50");}
            if(paperugency=="3-4days"){
                price=parseFloat("18.50");}
            if(paperugency=="4-5days"){
                price=parseFloat("17.50");}
            if(paperugency=="5-6days"){
                price=parseFloat("16.50");}
            if(paperugency=="7-9days"){
                price=parseFloat("15.50");}
            if(paperugency=="10-13days"){
                price=parseFloat("14.50");}
            if(paperugency=="14-20days"){
                price=parseFloat("13.95");}
            if(paperugency=="21-29days"){
                price=parseFloat("12.95");}
            if(paperugency=="30days+"){
                price=parseFloat("11.95");}
        }
        if(papertype==="editing" && aclevel==="UGT"){
            if(paperugency=="10-23hrs"){
                price=parseFloat("25.50");}
            if(paperugency=="24hrs"){
                price=parseFloat("23.50");}
            if(paperugency=="2-3days"){
                price=parseFloat("21.50");}
            if(paperugency=="3-4days"){
                price=parseFloat("19.50");}
            if(paperugency=="4-5days"){
                price=parseFloat("18.50");}
            if(paperugency=="5-6days"){
                price=parseFloat("17.50");}
            if(paperugency=="7-9days"){
                price=parseFloat("16.50");}
            if(paperugency=="10-13days"){
                price=parseFloat("15.50");}
            if(paperugency=="14-20days"){
                price=parseFloat("14.95");}
            if(paperugency=="21-29days"){
                price=parseFloat("13.95");}
            if(paperugency=="30days+"){
                price=parseFloat("12.95");}
        }
        if(papertype==="editing" && aclevel==="PHD"){
            if(paperugency=="10-23hrs"){
                price=parseFloat("30.50");}
            if(paperugency=="24hrs"){
                price=parseFloat("28.50");}
            if(paperugency=="2-3days"){
                price=parseFloat("26.50");}
            if(paperugency=="3-4days"){
                price=parseFloat("24.50");}
            if(paperugency=="4-5days"){
                price=parseFloat("23.50");}
            if(paperugency=="5-6days"){
                price=parseFloat("22.50");}
            if(paperugency=="7-9days"){
                price=parseFloat("21.50");}
            if(paperugency=="10-13days"){
                price=parseFloat("20.50");}
            if(paperugency=="14-20days"){
                price=parseFloat("19.95");}
            if(paperugency=="21-29days"){
                price=parseFloat("18.95");}
            if(paperugency=="30days+"){
                price=parseFloat("17.95");}
        }
        if(papertype==="editing" && aclevel==="MST"){
            if(paperugency=="10-23hrs"){
                price=parseFloat("28.50");}
            if(paperugency=="24hrs"){
                price=parseFloat("26.50");}
            if(paperugency=="2-3days"){
                price=parseFloat("24.50");}
            if(paperugency=="3-4days"){
                price=parseFloat("22.50");}
            if(paperugency=="4-5days"){
                price=parseFloat("21.50");}
            if(paperugency=="5-6days"){
                price=parseFloat("20.50");}
            if(paperugency=="7-9days"){
                price=parseFloat("19.50");}
            if(paperugency=="10-13days"){
                price=parseFloat("18.50");}
            if(paperugency=="14-20days"){
                price=parseFloat("17.95");}
            if(paperugency=="21-29days"){
                price=parseFloat("16.95");}
            if(paperugency=="30days+"){
                price=parseFloat("15.95");}
        }

        //writing service
        if(papertype==="writing" && aclevel==="HS"){
            if(paperugency=="10-23hrs"){
                price=parseFloat("33.50");}
            if(paperugency=="24hrs"){
                price=parseFloat("30.50");}
            if(paperugency=="2-3days"){
                price=parseFloat("20.50");}
            if(paperugency=="3-4days"){
                price=parseFloat("18.50");}
            if(paperugency=="4-5days"){
                price=parseFloat("17.50");}
            if(paperugency=="5-6days"){
                price=parseFloat("16.50");}
            if(paperugency=="7-9days"){
                price=parseFloat("15.50");}
            if(paperugency=="10-13days"){
                price=parseFloat("14.50");}
            if(paperugency=="14-20days"){
                price=parseFloat("12.50");}
            if(paperugency=="21-29days"){
                price=parseFloat("11.95");}
            if(paperugency=="30days+"){
                price=parseFloat("10.95");}
        }
        if(papertype==="writing" && aclevel==="CLLG"){
            if(paperugency=="10-23hrs"){
                price=parseFloat("35.50");}
            if(paperugency=="24hrs"){
                price=parseFloat("33.50");}
            if(paperugency=="2-3days"){
                price=parseFloat("22.50");}
            if(paperugency=="3-4days"){
                price=parseFloat("21.50");}
            if(paperugency=="4-5days"){
                price=parseFloat("20.50");}
            if(paperugency=="5-6days"){
                price=parseFloat("19.50");}
            if(paperugency=="7-9days"){
                price=parseFloat("18.50");}
            if(paperugency=="10-13days"){
                price=parseFloat("17.50");}
            if(paperugency=="14-20days"){
                price=parseFloat("16.95");}
            if(paperugency=="21-29days"){
                price=parseFloat("15.95");}
            if(paperugency=="30days+"){
                price=parseFloat("14.95");}
        }
        if(papertype==="writing" && aclevel==="UGT"){
            if(paperugency=="10-23hrs"){
                price=parseFloat("40");}
            if(paperugency=="24hrs"){
                price=parseFloat("35.50");}
            if(paperugency=="2-3days"){
                price=parseFloat("25.50");}
            if(paperugency=="3-4days"){
                price=parseFloat("24.50");}
            if(paperugency=="4-5days"){
                price=parseFloat("23.50");}
            if(paperugency=="5-6days"){
                price=parseFloat("22.50");}
            if(paperugency=="7-9days"){
                price=parseFloat("21.50");}
            if(paperugency=="10-13days"){
                price=parseFloat("20.50");}
            if(paperugency=="14-20days"){
                price=parseFloat("18.95");}
            if(paperugency=="21-29days"){
                price=parseFloat("17.95");}
            if(paperugency=="30days+"){
                price=parseFloat("16.95");}
        }
        if(papertype==="writing" && aclevel==="PHD"){
            if(paperugency=="10-23hrs"){
                price=parseFloat("45");}
            if(paperugency=="24hrs"){
                price=parseFloat("37.50");}
            if(paperugency=="2-3days"){
                price=parseFloat("31.50");}
            if(paperugency=="3-4days"){
                price=parseFloat("30.50");}
            if(paperugency=="4-5days"){
                price=parseFloat("28.50");}
            if(paperugency=="5-6days"){
                price=parseFloat("27.50");}
            if(paperugency=="7-9days"){
                price=parseFloat("26.50");}
            if(paperugency=="10-13days"){
                price=parseFloat("25.50");}
            if(paperugency=="14-20days"){
                price=parseFloat("23.50");}
            if(paperugency=="21-29days"){
                price=parseFloat("22.95");}
            if(paperugency=="30days+"){
                price=parseFloat("21.95");}
        }
        if(papertype==="writing" && aclevel==="MST"){
            if(paperugency=="10-23hrs"){
                price=parseFloat("42");}
            if(paperugency=="24hrs"){
                price=parseFloat("35.50");}
            if(paperugency=="2-3days"){
                price=parseFloat("30.50");}
            if(paperugency=="3-4days"){
                price=parseFloat("26.50");}
            if(paperugency=="4-5days"){
                price=parseFloat("25.50");}
            if(paperugency=="5-6days"){
                price=parseFloat("24.50");}
            if(paperugency=="7-9days"){
                price=parseFloat("23.50");}
            if(paperugency=="10-13days"){
                price=parseFloat("22.50");}
            if(paperugency=="14-20days"){
                price=parseFloat("20.50");}
            if(paperugency=="21-29days"){
                price=parseFloat("19.95");}
            if(paperugency=="30days+"){
                price=parseFloat("18.95");}
        }

        var total= "$" + (price*parseInt(pages)).toFixed(2);;
        document.getElementById('total').value=total;
    }
</script>

<span>Accuracy level</span>
<input type="text" id="acclevel">
 <span>Paper urgency</span>
<input type="text" id="paperurgency">
 <span>Pages</span>
<input type="text" id="pages">
 <span>Paper type</span>
<input type="text" id="papertype">
<input type="button" onclick="test()" value="Submit">
<h1>Total:</h1>
<input type="text" id="total">
</body>
```

Comment: dont i need an action listener so that when one fills my form once you press a button or something it calculates the total